# Using $.each for more complex JSON data

Tags: jquery

I understand how to use `$.each` to go through JSON data which looks like this:

```
{
    "one": "Singular sensation",
    "two": "Beady little eyes",
    "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

For example:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    echo '<div>' + val + '-' + key + '</div>';
});
```

But how do I use `$.each` to go though JSON data which looks like this:

```
{
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Innovation",
            "ordering": 0
        },
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Thought",
            "ordering": 0
        },
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Collaboration",
            "ordering": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Where I want to use the `id` and `name`.

Comment: `echo` ? Are you using JQuery at JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var complex_data = {
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Innovation",
            "ordering": 0
        },
         ...
    ]
}

//Use:
$.each(complex_data.d, function(i, val){
    //The following properties can be used in your code:
    val.id;
    val.name;
    //And also: val.__type, val.ordering
});
```

If your `complex_data` contains more keys like `d`, use:

```
$.each(complex_data, function(i, val){
    $.each(val, function(j, val){
        //The following properties can be used in your code:
        val.id;
        val.name;
        //Also: val.__type, val.ordering
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Same way

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(index, val2){
      console.log(val2.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.d, function(index, val) {
    echo '<div>' + val.id + '-' + val.name + '</div>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this code is fairly specific to your example so it might need a little tweaking, but you could do it like this:

```
data = {
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Innovation",
            "ordering": 0
        },
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Thought",
            "ordering": 0
        },
        {
            "__type": "Tab",
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Collaboration",
            "ordering": 0
        }
    ]
}

$.each(data.d, function(key, val) {
    $('#data').append('id: ' + val.id + ', name: ' + val.name + '<br />');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uxguf/